# Authentication Google Cloud APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I am trying to use BigQuery client and am getting authentication error:

```
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev397-1.23.0</version>
```

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401
>   Unauthorized

I don't have service account in path as I am an owner of the project and am logged in to my account via `gcloud auth login`. When I try `gcloud auth list` I see I am logged in with the credentials which has owner granted in my project. Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are logged via `gcloud auth login`, it doesn’t mean your application is going to use those credentials. You still need to authenticate using OAuth 2.0.

If you wish to authenticate with your user account, you can try generating an access token and passing it to the [GoogleCredential](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#credential) class (keep in mind tokens expire).

To generate the access token for your user credentials, use the gcloud tool:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Pass the generated token to the GoogleCredential class:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
```

I’m not very familiar to the google-api-services-bigquery API, but I think this is how you would use the credential:

```
Bigquery bigquery = Bigquery.builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY).setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```